# Perl: How to include scalar reference for DBIx::Class query information passed with ajax/json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, perl, dbix-class

I have a query I'm trying to pass from jquery/ajax/json to a perl script that will execute using DBIx::Class and return the results. I can get a basic query to work just fine, but am running into trouble when I have to include a scalar reference. My grasp on all the concepts around what I'm doing here is a little loose, so please forgive any inaccuracies.

Here is where I define the query parameters to pass to the perl script:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
  url: 'cgi-bin/getdata.cgi',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    table: 'Processes',
    search: {
      query_server:'SERVER1',
      query_time: {
        '>=':'now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY'
      }
    },
    attrib: {
      select: [
        'query_time',
        {avg:'bytes_processed'}
      ],
      order_by: 'query_time',
      group_by: 'query_time'
    }
  }),
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'POST',
  async: false
}).responseText;
```

Here is the part of the perl script that reads standard in, converts from json and runs the query:

```
while ( <STDIN> )
{
  $json .= $_;
}

my $query = from_json($json);

my $table = $query->{'table'};
my $search = $query->{'search'};
my $attrib= $query->{'attrib'};

print "Table:\n" . Dumper($table) . "\n";
print "Search:\n" . Dumper($search) . "\n";
print "Attrib:\n" . Dumper($attrib) . "\n";

my $retSet = $schema->resultset($table)->search( $search, $attrib );
my $retRow = $retSet->next;
```

And here is the output I get (with DBIC_TRACE enabled):

```
Table:
$VAR1 = 'Processes';

Search:
$VAR1 = {
          'query_time' => {
                            '>=' => 'now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY'
                          },
          'query_server' => 'SERVER1'
        };

Attrib:
$VAR1 = {
          'order_by' => 'query_time',
          'group_by' => 'query_time',
          'select' => [
                        'query_time',
                        {
                          'avg' => 'bytes_processed'
                        }
                      ]
        };

SELECT me.query_time, AVG( bytes_processed ) FROM processes me WHERE ( ( query_server = ? AND query_time >= ? ) ) GROUP BY query_time ORDER BY query_time: 'TSMCORP6', 'now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY'
```

The problem is that the `'now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY'` value needs to be a scalar reference in order to execute the query properly. If I build the query within the perl script (instead of passing from from the html file) like so:

```
my $search = {
  query_server => 'SERVER1',
  query_time   => {
    '>=' => \'now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY'
  }
};
```

then search data looks like this and executes the way I want it to:

```
Search:
$VAR1 = {
          'query_time' => {
                            '>=' => \'now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY'
                          },
          'query_server' => 'SERVER1'
        };
...
SELECT me.query_time, AVG( bytes_processed ) FROM processes me WHERE ( ( query_server = ? AND query_time >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ) GROUP BY query_time ORDER BY query_time: 'TSMCORP6'
```

Based on my understanding, I don't think passing the value as a reference makes any sense, so I'm trying to understand how to "convert" it once it's in the perl script. I've tried throwing in the backslash before it gets processed by `from_json`, but that did not work. Much thanks for any help!

Update: I was able to turn the value into a reference with the following code. However, this worked because I knew what value needed to be converted to a reference. Under normal circumstances, the value could be anywhere in the data structure. Could I flag the value with something like `!ref!` then search the entire data structure and convert each one I find? How would that look?

```
my $cond = $query->{'search'}->{'query_time'}->{'>='};
$query->{'search'}->{'query_time'}->{'>='}=\$cond;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that JSON doesn't have anything that maps cleanly to a reference type because it's just data. However, I think you're on the right track with pre-processing the incoming data and converting literal SQL to the references that DBIC expects. On the sending side, you could add a `literal_sql` flag to the objects that need special handling, and then you could use [`filter_json_object`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#filter_json_object) to find those keys, delete them, and create scalar string references.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use JSON;

my $json = <<'EOF';
{
    "table": "Processes",
    "search": {
        "query_server": "SERVER1",
        "query_time": {
            ">=": "now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY",
            "literal_sql": true
        }
    },
    "attrib": {
        "select": [
            "query_time", {
                "avg": "bytes_processed"
            }
        ],
        "order_by": "query_time",
        "group_by": "query_time"
    }
}
EOF

my $query = JSON
    ->new
    ->filter_json_object (sub {
        my $obj = shift;
        return unless $obj->{literal_sql};
        delete($obj->{literal_sql});

        my ($key, $val) = each(%$obj);
        $obj->{$key} = \"$val";
        return $obj;
    })
    ->decode($json);

dd($query);
```

Output:

```
{
  attrib => {
              group_by => "query_time",
              order_by => "query_time",
              select   => ["query_time", { avg => "bytes_processed" }],
            },
  search => {
              query_server => "SERVER1",
              query_time   => { ">=" => \"now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY" },
            },
  table  => "Processes",
}
```

Comment: Nice! I had been searching for a way to traverse the data structure and search for a tag. I didn't realize the JSON module had this filter functionality. It works great. Thank you.